# Show the following piecewise function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let$$f: [0,7] \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \begin{cases} 5 , 0 \le x < 4 \\ 0, x = 4 \\ 4, 4 < x \le 7\end{cases}$$
Consider the partition $\lbrace 0, 4 - \frac{1}{n}, 4 + \frac{1}{n}, 7\rbrace$ Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}: U(f, Pn)- L(f, Pn) < \epsilon$ and hence, f
is integrable on $[0, 7]$

I have the following:$$U(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta x_i = 5\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i = 5 \cdot ((4 - \frac{1}{n} - 0) + (4 + \frac{1}{n} - (4 - \frac{1}{n})) + (7-(4 - \frac{1}{n}))) = 5\cdot (7 + \frac{2}{n})$$ and $$ L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i\Delta x_i = 4\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i = 4 \cdot ((4 - \frac{1}{n} - 0) + (4 + \frac{1}{n} - (4 - \frac{1}{n})) + (7-(4 - \frac{1}{n}))) = 4\cdot (7 + \frac{2}{n})$$. Is this correct? I don't know what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between your upper sum and your lower sum is across the jump at 4. To calculate the upper sum, break it up into the 3 parts.  On the first part you have both upper and lower sum having the same value of $5\cdot (4-\frac 1 n)$
Similarly,  on the third part you have both upper and lower sum having $4\cdot (7-(4+\frac 1 n))$   Thus, $U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)$ will be exactly the difference across the jump discontinuity.

The upper sum has a max of 5 in the width $\frac 2 n$,  for a total of $\frac {10} n$.  The lower sum has a min of 0 in that width, so has a total of 0.  Thus
$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac {10} n$.  Now just pick $n>\frac {10} \epsilon$.